# Is there a name for this type of optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to optimize a linear function of $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ subject to constraints that look like

> $1(x_{2} \geq x_{1})(b_{1}x_{1} + b_{2}x_{2}) \geq 0$
>
> $1(x_{2} \leq x_{1})(b_{1}x_{1} + b_{2}x_{2}) \leq 0$

One way to attack this is to consider the cases $x_{2} \geq x_{1}$ and $x_{2} \leq x_{1}$ separately and solve two distinct linear programming problems. However, in my application I have a high-dimensional vector of $x$'s to optimize over and I don't know have any prior information about what order they should be in, so this type of approach would quickly become infeasible due to the combinatorics involved.

My question is whether this type of problem can be reformulated and/or if it has been studied and if so where I can read about it?

Comment: There is a typo in the second constraint: $b_1 \cdot x_2$ should be $b_1 \cdot x_1$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two constraints like this $$\begin{align}(x_2\ge x_1)(b_1x_1+b_2x_2)\ge0 \\ (x_2\le x_1)(b_1x_1+b_2x_2)\le0\end{align}$$ is one way of separating what was originally a single constraint for reasons particular to the method of solution.  In the case given above, the two separate constraints correspond to the single constraint $$(x_2-x_1)(b_1x_1+b_2x_2)\ge0.$$

If there is a name for this process of splitting one constraint into two, I have not seen it.  The effect is to **linearize** the constraints, and by recombining them you have **nonlinear constraints.**  Of course there is a vast body of work on the subject of nonlinear optimization.